# How to disable noise suppressor in android

Tags: java, android, audio, audio-recording

I am trying to record through phone's mic and it works for low end devices. But when I record with high end phones it is picking up lots of surrounding noises. My implementation is for 2.3 and above so i don't have API 16 available for noise suppressor. Please advice and thanks in advance.

In some forums I have read MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION will have no gain control, filtering and EQ applied as that needs pure signal. If thats true, it would help in my case.

In addition how to programatically determine which one is not doing any additional AGC and filtering?

Comment: What you're probably hearing here is not so much noise suppression, but automatic gain control.
This will have the effect of increasing the gain on background signals when there's nothing else.   If you  want high fidelity recordings, you will also need to disable the high-pass filter that is also applied to the microphone, or you won't get much below 150Hz.

Comment: Marko, it seems like disabling AGC and high pass filter needs modification in JNI code and would require root privileges. Is there a way to programatically disable these without fiddling with C++ core audio code.

Comment: thanks thanks and thanks for voice recognition option. Regards